# Look if points at given coordinates are True in a matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, indexing, selection

I have a numpy matrix A of size MxN of bool type.
Than I have an array B of ROWSx2 that contains, in each row, a pair of coordinates x,y. I would like to find the list of coordinates of the matrix A whose index is contained in the array A and whose value is equal to True.
I try with this command but it returns a 3d dimensional array and I don't understand why:

```
intersections = A[A[B] == True]
```

Comment: Add sample case?

Comment: Also, you might want to start accepting solutions to your old questions or to the least post some kind of feedback on them. I don't see any communication from your side. Doesn't look too good for people who take time out to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can index into the `A` with `B` with a tuple version or a sliced version to get the mask of the valid coordinates in `B`, like so -

```
mask = A[tuple(B.T)] #or A[B[:,0], B[:,1]]
```

Then, index into `B` for the valid coordinates -

```
out = B[mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: A
Out[43]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [44]: B
Out[44]: 
array([[5, 4],
       [1, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 4]])

In [45]: mask = A[tuple(B.T)]

# Mask of valid B coordinates
In [47]: mask
Out[47]: array([ True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [46]: B[mask]
Out[46]: 
array([[5, 4],  # [1,3] gone because A[1,3] = False
       [4, 4],
       [5, 4]])
```

Comment: Works great! But why is that transpose required in mask = A[tuple(B.T)] ?

Comment: @user1315621 If you run the sample, you would see the tuple output as : `tuple(B.T) = (array([5, 1, 4, 5]), array([4, 3, 4, 4]))`, i.e. first tuple is the tuple of row indices and second one for col indices, in essence we are indexing into each axis of `A` with each of the tuples for selecting the elements.